# Scraping tables from a webpage into python

Tags: python, bea

I am learning Spanish & to help me learn the different verbs and their conjugations I am making some flash cards to use on my phone.

I am trying to scrape the data from a web page [here is example page for one verb](https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/tener). On the page there are a few tables, I am interested in the first five (Present, Future, Imperfect, Preterite & Conditional) near the top.

I have heard the BeautifulSoup is good for these types of projects. However when I use the prettify method I can't find the tables in the text anywhere? I think I'm missing something, how can I get these tables in python?

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re

 URL = 'https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/tener.html'
 page = requests.get(URL)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 txt = soup.prettify()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the wrong url. Remove the ".html" from the URL variable and you will be able to find the tables (they're actually lists) in the output: `soup.find_all('div', class_='vPos')`